# Slow transitions on presenting a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am calling `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];`
 and it works just fine, but there is a delay in how long it takes to present. The `controller` is just a simple blank tableview. This view is being presented as a normal push.

Comment: Does this happen when testing on a device or simulator?

Comment: Do you have a lot of logic in init or viewDidLoad: ?

Comment: Instruments has a timing instrument. With this you can pin down what takes so long.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue thanks to instruments and @dasdom. Apparently there was a animation going on at the same time that was causing issues.