# ongoing animation causing delay while moving to another View Controller

Tags: ios, animation, swift2

ok so i  have a `button` which appears and hides with keyboard (when keyboard appears it also appears when i dismiss keyboard it also disappears with keyboard)

so when i'm pressing this `button` which opens another View controller the transition is not starting immediately there's a small amount of delay (which is not good)

my button's animations :

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let duration: Double = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double)
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()
    self.nextButtonConstraint.constant  = keyboardRectangle.height
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
        self.nextButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
    let duration: Double = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double)
     self.nextButtonConstraint.constant  = -50
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) {
          self.nextButton.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}
```

i tired to disable animations while button is pressed but it didn't worked  :

```
    @IBAction func nextButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("nextToPasswordSegue", sender: self)
     UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

according to this  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790678/slow-transitions-on-presenting-a-viewcontroller)'s answer  :

**Apparently there was a animation going on at the same time that was causing issues.**

any clue how can i fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and was having a delay when i attempted to move to the next controller. The way to fix it, for me, was to hide the keyboard (resignFirstResponder) before performing the segue. Then, you will want to run your perform segue line on the main queue, to make sure it fires immediately. Here's an example:

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("nextToPasswordSegue", sender: self)
}
```